# SQL CHECK Constraint logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `'DailyAllocations'`, which has a soft delete flag (`DATETIME, NULLABLE`) called 'Deleted', and the other significant column called `ProcessHistoryID` (`INT, NULLABLE`).

I need to add a contraint to the table, that will not allow a row to be soft deleted, while there is a value in the `ProcessHistoryID`.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.DailyAllocation
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_dont_delete_processed CHECK ((Deleted IS NULL AND ProcessHistoryID IS NULL) OR (Deleted IS NOT NULL AND ProcessHistoryID IS NULL))
```

But even though my data is valid, it's failing when I try to apply the containt:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint
>   "chk_dont_delete_processed". The conflict occurred in database
>   "MyDB", table "dbo.DailyAllocation".

It might be my logic, or else, I am doing something strange.

So, you can't have a deleted row, with a ProcessHistoryID. What am I doing wrong?

The following query returns no results, which means the data is currently clean:

```
SELECT *  FROM dbo.DailyAllocation WHERE Deleted IS NOT NULL AND ProcessHistoryID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Is the table empty? Are you sure none of existing rows violate the given constraint?

Comment: Just added a line of code that I use to check that the data is clean - and the result brings back nothing, which means the data is currently valid.

Comment: Have you checked `SELECT *  FROM dbo.DailyAllocation WHERE Deleted IS NULL AND ProcessHistoryID IS NOT NULL` query?

Comment: I'd say even `WHERE ProcessHistoryID IS NOT NULL`. The part of constraint related to `Deleted` is redundant.

Comment: Yes, it returns results, which is valid. You should only have a ProcessedHistoryID on non-deleted rows.

Comment: @Craig however such results are not allowed by your constraints.

Comment: Oh... If the check constraint returns TRUE - does it allow the row change? Or have I got it mixed up?

Comment: @Craig I think you got it a little mixed up :) Indeed, the rule is checked for being `TRUE` to allow insert/update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to have this rule `NOT (Deleted IS NOT NULL AND ProcessHistoryID IS NOT NULL)` - invert result of single not-allowed combination.